# Error when using macro to create a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I try and use a macro to create a pivot table, I always get an error message as shown below.

I think the problem here is related to the fact that the file name and sheet name always change. This is because I apply the macro to different files that I extract from SAP, and each file has a different name.

This is the part of my VBA code that is identified as problematic in VBE:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sophie & Toffee - Starting File!R1C1:R35150C37", Version:=6). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2" _
        , DefaultVersion:=6
```

As you can see it is taking as a source data the name of the tab of the file where I have recorded the macro. Is it possible to make it dynamic, or to avoid to consider the file name at all?

Please help me to find a solution to this error. It's killing me I've trying a lot of different codes I've found on the web, but I can't find a solution that works.

Comment: Are you always using the same installation of Excel (same version)?  I ran into a similar issue when dynamically creating a pivot chart when the macro was run in a different version of Excel

Comment: What is the error?